# Yii Dataprovider date sorting

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I have ArrayDataProvider with field of type DateTime - birthdate. 
I use that dataprovider for a gridview in view section.

Since birthdates include the birthyear the sorting is not working as expected. 
**Is there a way to somehow tell the sorting mechanism not to account years and only sort by month and day ?** A custom sort function perhaps ?

**Edit:** Something like `sort` in C++ where you can pass the compare function.

**Edited current solution description:**
My solution currently is to include a birthyear as a separate field in array and birthdate's years are set to current year. Now dates are from the same year and the sorting works. But separate field for birth year doesn't feel right. I wish i could get all necessary data from one date object.

This separate field grinds my gears. It's not perfect.

**Edit:**
Oh, and its Yii2

**Update**
There are also a PHP array sorting functions that take a compare callback - for example uasort that can be used on associative arrays like mine:

```
uasort($persons, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp( $b['date']->format('m-d'), $a['date']->format('m-d') );
});
```

Now i need to find the way to implement it into ArrayDataProvider. Any ideas here ?

Comment: kindly post the your code

Comment: I don't think there is any use of code here. Can you set custom sorting on ArrayDataProvider or any of the data providers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array dataprovider you can not use sorting of the database of course.

## Solution using Yii

To allow sorting by some expression you have to calculate the value beforehand and configure the sorting for the attribute to use the calculated value instead of the original one:

```
// assuming $data contains your data and 'birthdate' is the value you want to use for sorting

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]['sort_birthdate'] = date('m-d', strtotime($value['birthdate']));
}
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'birthdate' => [
                'asc' => [
                    'sort_birthdate' => SORT_ASC, 
                ],
                'desc' => [
                    'sort_birthdate' => SORT_DESC, 
                ],
                'label' => 'Date',
                'default' => SORT_ASC
            ],
            // list all other attributes here
        ],
    ]
]);
```

## Solution extending Yii

If you want a custom comparison function, you have to extend the Yii class to support this.
You can create a custom `ArrayDataProvider` class which extends from the one that comes with Yii and override the [sortModels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html#sortModels%28%29-detail)-method.

Comment: Well this is pretty much what is beeing done before the ArrayDataProvider object gets the data. I will add clarifying comment to question. Thanks.

Comment: This is not supported by Yii. Updated my answer to show how to extend Yii to add this.

Comment: I will look into it soon. Seems promising, but might end up being more overhead than is necessary for my simple application. Will be a good learning. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: By the way, when faced with the same problem, anyone, know that you're probably on the wrong track. As it seems to me that Yii truly can solve a lot of problems by design and to me all was solved by discovering "Virtual attributes" (beginner error). Now everything is perfect :)

Comment: Well, you did not mention that you are using AR at all. :)

Comment: Sorry. This topic didn't come out as clean as I had hoped. I think it's because I  was doing things just wrong and not realizing it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like

```
use yii\db\Expression;
$dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
................................
                'birthday' => [
                    'asc' => [
                        new Expression('DATE_FORMAT(birthday, "%m%d")') => SORT_ASC, 
                    ],
                    'desc' => [
                        new Expression('DATE_FORMAT(birthday, "%m%d")') => SORT_DESC, 
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Birthday',
                    'default' => SORT_ASC
                ],
................................
            ]
        ]);
```

I have not tried this.

What works for sure is to do something like this

```
$query->select([
                    new Expression('DATE_FORMAT(birthday, "%m%d") as show_date'), 
      .................................
                ]);
```

Then

```
    /**
     * Setup your sorting attributes
     * Note: This is setup before the $this->load($params) 
     * statement below
     */
     $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'show_date' => [
                'asc' => [
                    'sort_date' => SORT_ASC, 
                ],
                'desc' => [
                    'sort_date' => SORT_DESC, 
                ],
                'label' => 'Date',
                'default' => SORT_ASC
            ],
            'price',
            'gst',
            'cost',
            'quantity',
            'profit',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: I quess it would work if the data was from database. My data is from database, but before i can display it for human consumtion, preparations must be done. So I sadly can't use SQL for sorting dates.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html
Get the array, create a field in it with the data as you need it (in this case month-day) use it as a sorting attribute. Use the ArrayDataProvider in your GridView.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem - the extra field necessary for the sorting to work. But can I hook into the actual sorting of that field with a callback or smth. ? Compare function callback.

Comment: Why is that a problem? It is a field in an array. Go through the array, add a new field to it.. use the field in the array data provider. You said you already have to "prepare" it... add to your "preparation" this as well.

Comment: I got it, you have it like this already but you do not like the solution. Sorry I have no other idea, but I see what you are trying to do.